# What sorting algorithm would you use to sort large, almost sorted list

Tags: sorting, computer-science

Suppose you have an array of 3 billion integer that are almost sorted.
What sorting algorithm would be more appropriate (from amongst the "classic" ones)?
How about if the list was completely random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the authors of 'algorithms in a nutshell' who have compared sortingmethods for different usages your criteria would favor InsertionSort. See;

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/algorithms/9780596516246/sorting-algorithms/criteria_for_choosing_a_sorting_algorit

Answer (score 1):

I would use merge sort for both, because it is what is used in the standard unix sort() call, and you haven't provided any constraints which would alter that (like minimum time or minimum memory).

Comment: I see. I would have thought that Quicksorting was the preferred method for the second. Wasn't sure about the first though.

Comment: Quicksort can have bad performance depending on the initial order.  Heapsort is generally preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using insertion sort, which needs linear time if the input is (almost) sorted. Quick sort and merge sort have a time complexity of O(n log n) even if the input is sorted.